# What is the difference between Comet Technology and SignalR

Tags: comet, signalr

I searched this very badly.... Can anybody please tell me, what is the exact difference between SignalR and Comet Technology... I know that Comet does the same Client-Server Communication as SignalR... It pushes the data to the Client just as SignalR, then what is the difference between the 2. Please help.

Thank you!!!
Shivanand Arur.

Comment: SignalR is an implementation of Comet Technology.

Comment: If SignalR is the implementation of Comet Technology, then why don't we use Comet? There might be some drawbacks with Comet, because of which Comet evolved... I want to know the drawbacks of Comet...

Comment: To be more clear, SignalR created an abstraction over the different ways of implementing comet such as long-polling, forever-frame, http streaming and e.t.c. It allows you to focus on building your system and signalR take care of how you connect between your client and server.

Comment: Ooh great... So in other words, SignalR is nothing but Comet Technology but provides an abstraction over various concepts as u mentioned above.... So there is no actual difference between SignalR and Comet, instead SignalR can be termed as a child of Comet Technology... Please correct me if I am wrong... And thanks for replying... :)

Comment: SignalR was brought about as a way to solve the problem with dealing with various comet technology by creating an abstraction over the communication. So I guess you can say SignalR is the product of Comet Technology. You can read more about SignalR here: http://signalr.net/

Comment: Great thanks a lot... Now my doubts have got cleared more... Thank u so much.... :)

Comment: it would be really great if some one explain the difference point wise with sample situation like when to use signalr & when go for comet library. thanks